# Can I fly from state to state in Mexico with a US passport? Or do I need a Mexican passport to fly?

Tags: passports, us-citizens, mexico, domestic-travel

Ill be catching a flight from Tijuana to Mexico City. Can I travel with my US passport or will I need to get a Mexican passport?

Comment: Are you a citizen of Mexico?

Comment: (+1) I think it's a reasonable question, some countries do require citizens to use a local ID for all official purposes so even if you don't cross a border, it could be forbidden to use a US passport if you are a Mexican citizen.

Answer (score 2):

You can't get a Mexican passport unless you are Mexican citizen.

Generally speaking, for travel you need a government issued identification document with your photo - a passport *any passport* qualifies for this.

Depending on the flight, you may also provide other forms of identification in lieu of the passport (for example, a driver's license is accepted on most domestic flights in the US - even from non-citizens).

In fact, depending on the circumstances - the document doesn't even need to be valid/current (for example, if you are trying to prove your right to enter by citizenship, an expired passport will suffice).

Comment: That's a new one to me - professional certificate - interesting.

Answer (score 0):

depends, usually they do not ask you for one if it has your picture if you are travel withing México, because they have no way to prove you are mexican, so as long it has your picture, you can travel with it without problem